# Altering cell colour hides cell border in LyX

Tags: tables, color, lyx, colortbl

I'm probably doing something simple wrong, but I'm having the following problem.  I've got a table with two columns, on the left there are multirows with coloured cells, on the right there are normal cells which are each coloured individually. Hopefully this is clear in the following pictures:

[image: lyx table]

[image: pdf table]

As you can see, the cells on the right in the generated table do not have the correct borders, even though they seem to be fine in LyX.

Does anybody know what might be causing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the tex markup generated it is hard to be sure but especially if it prints OK but just looks bad on screen then it is most likely just an artifact of your pdf viewer. TeX positions the lines from hline and the rules for the coloured backgrounds very exactly but the viewer has to snap them to pixel boundaries and if this can cause the background to obscure a thin rule. Try increasing `\arrayrulewidth` to reduce the effect.